# Make [meta-stack-exchange] a synonym of [meta]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, meta, synonym-request

Can we please make [meta-stack-exchange](/questions/tagged/meta-stack-exchange) a synonym of [meta](/questions/tagged/meta)? Because the purpose of both tags is same that is for questions related to Meta Stack Exchange itself (meta meta). We are using [meta](/questions/tagged/meta) tag for the same purpose from the beginning of the MSO.

[Excerpt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/meta/info) of the tag [meta](/questions/tagged/meta):

> Governing meta for all of Stack Exchange

[meta](/questions/tagged/meta) tag is not for per site meta (e.g. [Meta.Sports.SE](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/)). For those questions we already have a tag [per-site-meta](/questions/tagged/per-site-meta). Also, [mse](/questions/tagged/mse) is already a synonym of [meta](/questions/tagged/meta).

Comment: I have already suggested [a synonym](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/meta/synonyms). Those who agree and eligible can vote on it.

Comment: Doesn't 'meta' also refer to *per child site* metas?

Comment: Ah, no, the synonyms already there and the wiki make that clear. Voted on the synonym.

Comment: Reading the wiki for meta-stack-exchange, seems like it might be a synonym for [tag:mso-mse-split].

Comment: @psubsee2003 - It seems but it's name doesn't seems to be a synonym for mso-mse-split.

Comment: @hims056 agreed, but it was created before the split when questions asking about mse needed a tag.  Judging by the questions only the oldest one doesn't seem appropriate for a [tag:meta] tag.  So I when ahead and voted for your synonym was well and removed the one tag I didn't think needed a [meta] tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been completed; the [meta-stack-exchange](/questions/tagged/meta-stack-exchange) tag is now a synonym of [meta](/questions/tagged/meta).

As seen on the [tag synonyms page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms):

[image: screenshot of synonyms page]